# Why does a binary tree using unsafe code have bad memory access in debug mode, but not release?

Tags: pointers, rust, raw-pointer

I am trying to implement a binary tree in unsafe Rust and it appears to be a difference between debug and release.

This code executed on debug is very likely to access wrong memory address, but if compiled in release mode it seems to be fine.

It is totally possible that I made a mistake as I am quite new to raw pointers, but having different output is really strange.

Is my different output really a sign of wrong memory access? Is that expected when working with unsafe Rust? It is the sign of code smell somehow?

In debug mode, the output on my machine is:

```
constructing tree
5
constructed
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
value added
```

In release mode, the output on my machine is:

```
constructing tree
5
constructed
5
value added
```

Here the code, reduced as much as I could.

```
use std::ptr;

struct Node {
    value: f32,
    node_left: *mut Node,
    node_right: *mut Node,
}

impl Node {
    pub fn from_value(value: f32) -> Node {
        println!("{}", value);
        Node {
            value: value,
            node_left: ptr::null_mut(),
            node_right: ptr::null_mut(),
        }
    }

    fn get_value(&self) -> f32 {
        self.value
    }
}

pub struct BinaryTree {
    root: *mut Node,
}

impl BinaryTree {
    pub fn from_value(value: f32) -> BinaryTree {
        let mut node = &mut Node::from_value(value);
        BinaryTree { root: node }
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, value: f32) {
        println!("{}", unsafe { self.root.as_mut() }.unwrap().get_value());
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("constructing tree");
    let mut x = BinaryTree::from_value(5.0f32);
    println!("constructed");
    x.add(2f32);
    println!("value added");
}
```

I ran this on Ubuntu 18.04 in an Oracle VM using Rust 1.32.0.

Comment: Sometime rustc can have bug... but that very very very very unlikely to be the case if your code contains unsafe.

Comment: You are taking the address of the stack, this pointer is not valid after the function end.

Comment: What's your motivation for using pointers in this case? By doing so, you're essentially working around all of the safeties that Rust provides.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, so i should return a box<Node> from the function? my motivation are: learn to play with ptr, and learn to implement common datastructure. in rust tree or linked list seems really heavy to put in place keepping all the safety.

Comment: You can use `Option<Box<Node>>` for your child nodes for instance.

Comment: *tree or linked list seems really heavy to put in place keepping all the safety* — yes, because making safe yet performant data structures is **hard** in general. That's why we don't reimplement them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `BinaryTree::from_value`, you're creating a new `Node` and then storing a pointer to it. However, the `Node` is allocated on the stack, and is dropped before you call `BinaryTree::add`. Because you're using pointers and `unsafe` instead of references, the Rust compiler can't warn you about lifetime issues like these.

As to why this fails in debug mode but works in release mode, it may be due to an optimization that's only enabled for release mode.

Comment: *an optimization that's only enabled for release mode* — yes, it's very likely that the function is inlined and thus there's no popping of the stack.